# Convert human readable .dat file to relational database

Tags: python, database, pandas, dataframe, text-processing

I have a bunch of text files that contain human readable text. I want to extract any tabular information present in the text file and create a relational database out of it. The caveat here is that each text file has all sorts of descriptive texts and a bunch of sections that can be converted to relational database. Is there any sophisticated way to extract such tabular information from text and create a relational database out of it?
A sample of the dummy text file would be:

```
***************************************************
This file contains information about products and their prices
Date: 2020-08-20
Version: 9
***************************************************

Begin Food
    Milk 2.9
    Coffee 2.1
    Pastry 3.5
    Apple 1.5
    Milk 3.9
    Coffee 1.5
    Pastry 4.6
    Apple 2.9
End Food

***************************************************
Addition to the product catalog
Date: 2020-08-20
Version: 9.5
***************************************************

***************************************************
    Modification Log:

    i-1:    01/28/2013
        : Initial implementation of catalog
        : for task 234.

***************************************************

Begin Requirement_List
    PID: "Low Milk" {
        Begin Grade A
            ID: "1" {L1: 0, L2: 0.7}
            ID: "2" {L1: 1,L2: 1.2}
            ID: "3" {L1: 15,L2: 3.2}
            ID: "4" {L1: 15,L2: 3.2}
            ID: "5" {L1: 15,L2: 3.2}
            ID: "6" {L1: 15,L2: 3.2}
            ID: "7" {L1: 15,L2: 3.2}
            ID: "8" {L1: 15,L2: 3.2}
        End Grade A
    }

    PID: "High Milk" {
        Begin Grade B
            ID: "1" {L1: 4, L2: 3.7}
            ID: "2" {L1: 15,L2: 3.2}
            ID: "3" {L1: 15,L2: 3.2}
            ID: "4" {L1: 15,L2: 3.2}
            ID: "5" {L1: 15,L2: 3.2}
            ID: "6" {L1: 15,L2: 3.2}
            ID: "7" {L1: 15,L2: 3.2}
            ID: "8" {L1: 15,L2: 3.2}
        End Grade B
    }
End Requirement_List
```

Comment: I believe you need to post this question to AI/ML forum. This definitely needs a machine learning model to achieve, unless you write your own parser based on the structure.

Comment: what did you try? Where is your code? Split problem to smaller problems and then try to resolve them. You have date separated by `**`  so you could every part tread as separated problem.